# Why is my Kendo Tree not showing my JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I can't get a Kendo tree to display any data for the life of me! I've got a WebApi that returns this JSON structure:

```
"Id":3,
"ParentId":0,
"FieldName":"",
"Value":"",
"OperationId":7,
"Children":[{
     "Id":4,
     "ParentId":3,
     "FieldName":"",
     "Value":"",
     "OperationId":8,
     "Children":[{
         "Id":5,
         "ParentId":4,
         "FieldName":"xyz",
         "Value":"abcd",
         "OperationId":5,
         "Children":null,
         "HasChildren":false
          },    
         "Id":6,
         "ParentId":4,
         "FieldName":"asdf",
         "Value":"somedata",
         "OperationId":5,
         "Children":null,
         "HasChildren":false
         }],
   "HasChildren":true},{.....blah blah you get the picture
```

My JS is as follows:

```
var Tree;
var Root;

$(document).ready(function () {
    Root = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetData", "MyController")",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 'someId': 1 }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    hasChildren: "HasChildren"
                }
            }
        });

        Tree = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            dataSource: Root,
            dataValueField: "Id",
            dataTextField: "OperationId",               
        });
    });
```

What am I doing wrong here? Fiddler and chrome show a good result from the WebApi call with the json data. When the page loads, the Kendo tree control shows the Loading spinner and then it blanks out. I've seriously spent hours on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the demo @ http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/remote-data.html should show you everything you need to know to get this one in the bag.

Comment: The demo uses jsonp data and I'm not exporting my data like that. I'm exporting it with json.

Answer (score 0):

The HasChildren attribute seems to be a child property of the Children attribute. It's not directly off the top object in your hierarchy similar to ID which conflicts with your schema definition. Could that be the culprit?

Comment: Yeah, the first thing I'd say is that your JSON model is an err...there is no closing braces for the Children of the Children. And then, yes, the 'Has Children' property seems odd as well. Post an actual model if you feel as though these comments are not appropriate to your question.

Comment: The object structure is like this: Object {Id, FieldName, Value, (some other properties), HasChildren, Children(array)}. Isn't this correct? Shouldn't the HasChildren property be at the same level as the Children array?

Comment: The sample JSON you provided in the question has the HasChildren property inside the Children array. Perhaps you did not paste your JSON data correctly in the question.